# nested lambdas cause compiler to run out of heap

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm writing some code which passes lambda functions to a suite of recursive functions. Some of these lambda functions are nested inside other lambda functions. I think I'm writing valid code but I'm getting a `fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space` error.

Here is a much cut down version of the code

```
struct Null
{
    template <typename SK>
    static void match(SK sk)
    {
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Repetition
{
    template <typename SK>
    static void match(SK sk)
    {  // <--------------------------------- error message points to this line
        T::match([]() { match([]() {}); });
    }
};

int main()
{
    using Test = Repetition<Null>;
    Test::match([](){});
}
```

Now this minimal version doesn't make much sense but it has the same compiler error. I've indicated the line with the error above.

My question is, is this a compiler bug/limitation or is my code invalid in some way?

Compiler is Visual Studio 2022 compiling C++20.

Thanks

Comment: `T::match([]() { match([]() {}); });` is this not infinite recursion? Maybe I am misreading?

Comment: It is, but it shouldn't matter right? Not for the compiler anyway, it's a runtime issue.

Comment: @AndyG Not in this case because the lambda with the recursive call is never called.

Comment: Each lambda is a unique type, so it would matter to the compiler

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour in the latest preview VS2022, as well as gcc 11 and 12. All of them choke on this code.

Comment: `T::match(sk);`  <--this does not infinitely recurse. Is this what you meant to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-1)

> The type of a lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type

To instantiate `Repetition::match`, the compiler must instantiate `Null::match` which requires an instantiation of `Repetition::match`... and so on. Each time the compiler recurses, `[]() {}` is treated as a brand new type, ad infinitum.

To get it to stop recursing, replace your call with:

```
T::match(sk);
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense, Unfortunately the real code is more complicated. The inner lambda is different from the lambda passed to `sk`.

Comment: @john if you can come up with something closer to your real code that still exhibits this issue, ask a new question and I'll be happy to look.

Comment: That would be tricky. Because the inner lambda captures values in the `Repetition::match` function I'm not sure I can avoid this problem. Maybe I need to write an old fashioned functor.

Comment: @john: If you can get it to work properly using functors, you can ask a question along the lines of "What is the equivalent with lambdas"?

Comment: I posted a follow up question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72527510/why-does-each-instantiation-of-a-lambda-function-result-in-a-unique-type

Answer (score 0):

While both VS2022 and gcc 11 and 12 just crash on this, clang does manage to give an error message:

```
<source>:15:25: fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024
        T::match([]() { match([]() {}); });
                        ^
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: (skipping 1015 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:22:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:22:17)>' requested here
    Test::match([](){});
          ^
1 error generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:15:25: fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024
        T::match([]() { match([]() {}); });
                        ^
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: (skipping 1015 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:15:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:15:31)>' requested here
<source>:22:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Repetition<Null>::match<(lambda at <source>:22:17)>' requested here
    Test::match([](){});
          ^
1 error generated.
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```